# SQLAlchemy: object has no attribute '_sa_adapter'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I run into a very strange bug, quite hard to reproduce: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_adapter'`. It seems it would come from one-to-many relationship, but everything looks fine and I can't get to simply reproduce the bug. If I run the test suite alone, there's no bug, it only happens when the whole test are run. Maybe it comes from something that was not cleaned properly...

Here is the full stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ca/[REDACTED].py", line 79, in setUp
    self.client.save()
  File "/Users/ca/[REDACTED].py", line 370, in save
    Session.add(self)
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 113, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1223, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1238, in _save_or_update_state
    halt_on=self._contains_state):
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1814, in cascade_iterator
    parent_dict, visited_states, halt_on))
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 817, in cascade_iterator
    get_all_pending(state, dict_)
  File "/Users/ca/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.5-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 775, in get_all_pending
    current = getattr(current, '_sa_adapter')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_adapter'
```

Do you know where it could come from?

Thanks,

Chx

Comment: Quite hard to tell without the help.. Would https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/AKHNAUb1tUY give you some clues?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's why I asked it here too. I'm just trying to understand what this error means, because it seems related to a bad cleanup in my test suite... It would be too long and too specific to provide it here.

Comment: I meant to say without the 'code', rather than without the 'help' of course. Well, error itself means that you're trying to do something like Object._sa_adapter, whereas Object in that case is a list, rather than an object. That's as far as I can deduce, sorry :) .. ow yeah, that line is present in the stacktrace. that helps a bit. basically, as per, http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr, it's equivalent to example i tried to depict before and current is a list in that case, when statement expects it to be an object, containing a named attribute _sa_adapter.

Comment: In your code, do you maybe assign a `list` to an attribute that is a collection in a relationship in some way which SA does not handle correctly? In `SA` the collections are usually not python `list`, but objects like [`sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/collections.html#sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList)

Comment: it means you are manipulating an instrumented object inappropriately - such as saying, myobject.__dict__[somekey] = [1, 2, 3].    Direct `__dict__` manipulation is not supported on mapped objects.

Comment: In fact, somewhere in my test I was doing myobjec.__class__.somekey = [1, 2, 3] (yes, the very same list you are giving as example). zzzeek, could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you are manipulating an instrumented object inappropriately – such as saying, `myobject.__dict__[somekey] = [1, 2, 3]`. Direct `__dict__` manipulation is not supported on mapped objects.

Comment: How do I handle such a case?http://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek pl. guide where I am trying to use M2M relation using between models and def __init__(self, **kwargs): return self.__dict__.update(kwargs) method for updating the models

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but for anyone viewing later, you want to make sure your values are going through **setattr** so SA's mappings have an opportunity to intercept. So you can do:

```
obj.attr = myval
```

or

```
setattr(obj, 'attr', myval)
```

Comment: Because you have a list of foreign keys you have to get the objects from the database or create them before set the attribute. 
Then add one by one add them using obj.attr.append(object)

Answer (score 0):

My case is another session is still opening in other thread(scheduler one). So, I have that thread closes the session after jobs have been activated and the http server thread works like a charm.