# Appropriately altering __setattr__ method for mapped objects

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, magic-methods

So, I have a web application where there's a certain database object with attributes I would like to cache in a `redis` store. Relatively simple to do manually, with something like below:

```
db_object.update({<attribute>: <value>})
redis.set(db_object.id, <value>)
```

The issue here is that it's an attribute that is changed in many places throughout the codebase. Doesn't mean this approach won't work, it just means that it makes for code that is very repetitive. I would much rather just have a wrapper for the cache that I can access directly whenever I need to. This means that any time I change the particular attribute I'm interested in I would like to update my redis store, theoretically like so:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    if name == <attribute>:
        redis.set(self.id, value)
```

which would solve all my problems. The only issue is that, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746922/sqlalchemy-object-has-no-attribute-sa-adapter) I cannot directly modify the `__dict__` in mapped objects. How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice way to approach this on another question. Can just call the super method instead of directly altering `__dict__`

Method below has the desired effect:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == <attribute>:
        redis.set(self.id, value)
    super(Dataset, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```